# How to change between classes every specific time using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click the close button, the .pupuppro class is changed to .pupuppro.active. How do I return it to .pupuppro without updating the page after a specified time

```js
function toggle() {
  var video = document.querySelector(".pupuppro")
  video.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

```css
.pupuppro {
  background: #0000007a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: visible;
}

.pupuppro.active {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#proo {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<div class="pupuppro">
  <h1 class="text">good morning</h1>
  <i id="proo" onclick="toggle();">close</i>
</div>
```

Comment: declare a timer function and after your specified time add `element.classList.remove("active")`

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using `setTimeout`

```
function toggle() {
  const milliseconds = 2000;
  var video = document.querySelector(".pupuppro")
  video.classList.add("active")
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    video.classList.remove("active")
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, milliseconds)
}
```

e.g.

```js
function toggle() {
  const milliseconds = 2000;
  var video = document.querySelector(".pupuppro")
  video.classList.add("active")
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    video.classList.remove("active")
    clearTimeout(timeout)
  }, milliseconds)
}
```

```css
.pupuppro {
  background: #0000007a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  visibility: visible;
}

.pupuppro.active {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#proo {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
```

```html
<div class="pupuppro">
  <h1 class="text">good morning</h1>
  <i id="proo" onclick="toggle();">close</i>
</div>
```

Comment: When I add it, the shutdown button does not work

Comment: shutdown button, do you mean the close button? I've updated the answer so that you can run the code snippet. the close button is working as expected.